# Filling a PDF Form with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Im looking to create a new PDF in PHP, given a PDF form template and some PHP variables to input into the PDF template. Whats the best or recommended way of tackling this? Essentially the end goal is that users will fill out this pdf form and there inputs will be saved to a database. Then later being able retrieve the inputs from the database and outputting it to the PDF. Any help with this would be great, Thanks.

Comment: TCPDF is a quite popular solution to generate PDF with PHP, it can generate but cannot read though. You need FPDI to import data from pre-existing PDF file into a TCPDF project.

Comment: Why don't you use a html form for the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line tool called pdftk (PDF Toolkit).

See https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

You can call the command line from php, and the command is

`pdftk` formfile.pdf `fill_form` fieldinfo.fdf `output` outputfile.pdf `flatten`

You will need to find the format of an FDF file in order to generate the info to fill in the fields.